# Texlipse opening stale file on OSX

Tags: eclipse, macos, pdf, latex, texlipse

I have 'texlipse' setup on my eclipse workspace. On compiling a certain tex file for the first time everything goes fine and the pdf file opens up in adobe reader, but on subsequent builds the same old file is opened again unless I force quit adobe reader. i.e. changes do not reflect on the pdf file that shows up an a build and run call unless adobe reader has been closed using 'Command + Q'.

How do i make sure that adobe reader always opens the latest built file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your default pdf application to Preview, you wont have to reopen the file every time you make changes. Preview refreshes once the source file has changed.